# Feynarts not working

Tags: packages, feyncalc

Update: I use FeynArts-3.7 with FeynCalc 8.2.0. When I enter **`<<HighEnergyPhysics`FeynCalc`(sorry I cannot write primes here)
I get a long list of error which I suspect is because of conflict between FeynArts and FeynCalc. Also When I write e.g.`CreateTopologies[1,1->2]` it turns red and when I hold the pointer on it it says: *a symbol occurs in more than one place: One of the definitions is shadowed. * what is this and how can I fix it?

When I do as described in [MSE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7966/feynarts-not-working-properly) I get the following error messages:

```
$LoadPhi = True; $LoadFeynArts = True; <<HighEnergyPhysics`FeynCalc`; 
Loading FeynCalc from /Users/MyName/Library/Mathematica/Applications/HighEnergyPhysics
FeynCalc 8.2.0 For help, type ?FeynCalc, open FeynCalcRef8.nb or visit www.feyncalc.org
Loading PHI 
WARNING! Your FeynArts installation is not complete or the version you have cannot be used with this version of FeynCalc.
FeynArts can be downloaded at www.feynarts.de
Loading FeynArts, see www.feynarts.de for documentation
FeynArts not found. Please install FeynArts, e.g., in
/Users/MyName/Library/Mathematica
and reload FeynCalc
FeynArts can be downloaded from www.feynarts.de
```

There's already a thread with a similar problem but none of the solutions there work for my case. I'm on a MacOSX Mathematica 10. This is what I do:

I install feyncalc by writing in Mathematica

```
Import["http://www.feyncalc.org/install.m"]
```

After this I can play around with feyncalc and it works i.e. `DiracSlash[a]`, `DiracTrace` and so on. But I don't know how to make FeynArts work. I know that there is a FeynArts-3.7 folder in `/users/myname/library/mathematica/applications/HighEnergyPhysics`  where one also finds e.g. the folder `Phi` `qcd` `Models` etc.

When I try to do a very simple example like the one suggested in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.2231.pdf nothing happens: I write

```
top = CreateTopologies[1, 1 → 2]
```

(Mathematica only prints the text "CreateTopologies[1, 1 → 2]") and then

```
ins = InsertFields[top, F[4,{3}] → {F[4,{2}], V[1]}]
```

Finally

```
amp = CreateFeynAmp[ins]
```

Actually before I reinstalled everything something did happen, but that was an error as is described in this MSE link: [FeynArts not working properly](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7966/feynarts-not-working-properly) but now I cannot even reproduce this error.

So my questions are, how can one generate the simplest FeynArts example and if so it would be nice to have it working together with FeynCalc?

Answer (score 2):

Provided that FeynArts was patched properly, which is mostly the case if the [automatic installer](https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/wiki/Installation#st_automatic_installation) is used, one can look at various examples involving FeynArts in the `Examples` subfolder of the FeynCalc installation:

```
<< FeynCalc`
FileNameJoin[{$FeynCalcDirectory, "Examples"}]
```