# FeynArts package fails to load

Tags: warning-messages, packages, feyncalc

This is definitely a duplicate of [FeynArts not working properly](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7966/feynarts-not-working-properly). However, that post dates back 5 years. I am currently on Mathematica 11.0.1.0 with Windows 10 as my OS. I have been trying to load the FeynArts package but to no avail.

I have followed the route of automatic installation prescribed in the FeynCalc wiki(includes an option to install patched version of FeynArts 3.9):

```
1. Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/master/install.m"]
2. InstallFeynCalc[]
```

Despite an apparent clean installation, FeynArts doesn't seem to be loaded.

Loading code:

```
$LoadFeynArts = True;
<<FeynCalc`;
```

which returned the output:

> FeynCalc is already loaded! To reload it, please restart the kernel.

Now, when I tried the simplest piece of code one can have via this package:

```
CreateTopologies[1,1->1]
Paint[%]
```

it just returns the input back!

How to get this package(FeynArts) working side by side with FeynCalc?

Comment: *Did* you load the package? Or did you just install it?

Comment: @Szabolcs I did install using FeynCalc installer

Comment: You did not answer the question. Did you *load* the package?  When you have a problem, please show all steps needed to reproduce it, not merely some of them. What command did you use to load the package?

Comment: I tried :  $LoadFeynArts = True;
             <<FeynCalc`;

Answer (score 3):

The problem is actually a very simple one: once `FeynCalc` has been loaded, you cannot reload it or load `FeynArts`, `TARCER`, `PHI`, `FeynHelpers` or any other add-on without restarting the kernel. So doing something like

```
<<FeynCalc`

...

$LoadFeynArts=True;
<<FeynCalc`
```

will not work. You need to either issue `Quit[]` or go to `Evaluation -> Quit Kernel -> Local`.

I thought that the error message ending with `To reload it, please restart the kernel.` seems to be pretty clear on on what one should do, but somehow there is still some confusion.

Comment: I was not able to get FeyArts to load even after restarting kernel. I therefore manually extracted the latest tarball for the same and patched it to resolve conflicts with FeynCalc

Comment: In principle, if you choose to install FeynArts while running the automatic installer, it should be patched immediately afterwards. Not sure what went wrong in your case.

Answer (score 2):

It worked after implementing a *forced patch* as mentioned in the wiki https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/wiki/FeynArts under **Patching FeynArts for FeynCalc 9.x and above**.